# Connecting Xbox 360 wireless controller to Samsung galaxy tab 3

Tags: samsung, usb-on-the-go

I am attempting to connect a wireless Xbox controller to my tab 3 however after following the instructions [Here](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/how-to-use-xbox-controllers-on-your-android-device.882265/) and [Here](http://www.xda-developers.com/pair-a-wireless-xbox-360-controller-with-a-nexus-7/) but to no luck ive also tried using logcat to find out the vendor and product id of the adapter incase it was different but still no luck as they are the exact same numbers as in the posts.

any help with figuring this out would be much appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work when wired? That would help narrow things down a bit.

Comment: I don't have a wired controller to test it with unfortunately

Comment: You can verify the OTG setup by connecting a wired USB mouse. An arrow cursor should appear and you should be able to drive the device via mouse. Just trying to narrow things down to whether the problem is with the Xbox hack or something else.

Comment: Yes mice and keyboards work as well as storage media it seems to only be the Xbox wireless receiver. The receiver does also light up however the controller won't connect

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried to follow this post https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289047/i-want-to-connect-my-wireless-xbox-360-controller-to-my-galaxy-s6-rooted but as it is for a different device, the file I need to copy as root is different, and I don't know which.